# Angular cannot bind data from parent component

Tags: angular, angular-services, 2-way-object-databinding

parent component emit data via service to the child component, but I cannot bind data to the child component (in select):

```
<!-- Parent -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="projects" class="text-dark ">Projects:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="projects" name="project" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject">
      <option *ngFor="let projectElement of projects"
          [ngValue]="projectElement">{{projectElement.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<!-- Child -->
<app-tasks [project]="selectedProject?.tasks"></app-tasks>
```

When there is whole HTML structure of the child component in HTML file of the parent component, it works fine, but I want to separate child component with selector like in the example above.

What's wrong in binding?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cascading-dropdown)

Comment: You will have to use an inject-able service to share data across components. If you only want to pass an id or a simple string then you can do that using pathparam coupled with a router link.

Comment: Did you solved? The demo seems to work

Comment: Yes, guys have noticed a mistake in iteration with wrong variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

I just changed your tasks component to reference your tasks.  you had a variable in there that didn't exist so i just changed it for you

```
    <option *ngFor="let task of this.project">{{ task.name }}
```

also i added a ngOnChanges for your console log just to show the output

```
  ngOnChanges() {
     console.log(this.project);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/cascading-dropdown-jewucx

Answer (score 1):

your solution is to change:

In tasks.component.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tasks" class="text-dark ">Tasks:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="projects">
    <option *ngFor="let task of project">{{ task.name }}  <--- you had here selectedProject, I changed it to project
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```